# User login in Django + React

Tags: reactjs, django, security

I have looked through quite a few tutorials (e.g. [this](https://hackernoon.com/110percent-complete-jwt-authentication-with-django-and-react-2020-iejq34ta), [this](https://blog.devgenius.io/django-react-authentication-part-2-ea626688165e), and [this](https://youtu.be/kfpY5BsIoFg)) on user authentication in a full-stack Django + React web app. All of them simply send username and password received from the user to the backend using a POST request. It seems to me that, if the user leaves the computer unattended for a minute, anyone can grab his password from the request headers in network tools in the browser. Is this a valid concern that must be taken care of? If so, how should these examples be modified? A tutorial / example of the correct approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Just hash the passwords before sending them over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that, if the user leaves the computer unattended for a minute, anyone can grab his password from the request headers in network tools in the browser

1. If the user leaves the computer unattended then what you are describing will probably be the least of his/her worries.
2. Authentication is a complex topic, if you really do not want to use existing libraries that handle this for you then you will need to spend quite some time to get things right (knowing that even then, risk 0 does not exist), the most basic thing being to never store plain text credentials on your DB and using https to transmit them over an encrypted connection. You can then start thinking about JWTs, avoiding local storage, CSRF and securing cookies, refresh tokens, etc.
3. You cannot do much however about cases like the one you describe of people giving away access to their computers or sharing their passwords with others except reminding them they should never do such a thing.

On a side note, if the user didn't have the network monitoring tool open when making the request to your website, opening it afterwards will not show the previously submitted plain text credentials (there are workarounds to this however)